# Posts_orderby not executed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by, advanced-custom-fields

I want to order products by nearest locations after a location is entered in a search form. I use the Google Maps from ACF to assign location to products and the field is called "address". I have also Google places autocomplete for my form and the ACF google maps radius search plugin. My search form redirect to an URL with the lat and lng variables:

```
/?s=&post_type=product&lat=43.26768079999999&lng=6.640710899999931
```

The plugin is supposed to order products from this url. The lat and lng are well passed in the URL.

Below are two functions of the plugin :

```
// Join for searching metadata
function acf_google_maps_search_join_to_WPQuery($join) {

    global $wpdb;

    $acf_gms = new acf_gms; 
    $table_name = $acf_gms->table_name();

    if ( 
        isset($_GET['lat']) && !empty($_GET['lat']) 
        && isset( $_GET['lng']) && !empty($_GET['lng']) 
         ) {

        $join .= " LEFT JOIN {$table_name} AS acf_gms_geo ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id ";

    }

    return $join;

}
add_filter('posts_join', 'acf_google_maps_search_join_to_WPQuery');



// ORDER BY DISTANCE
function acf_google_maps_search_orderby_WPQuery($orderby) {


     if ( 
        isset($_GET['lat']) && !empty($_GET['lat']) 
        && isset( $_GET['lng']) && !empty($_GET['lng']) 
         ) {

        $lat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lat'] );
        $lng = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lng'] );

        $orderby = " (POW((acf_gms_geo.lng-{$lng}),2) + POW((acf_gms_geo.lat-{$lat}),2)) ASC";

    }

    return $orderby;

}
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'acf_google_maps_search_orderby_WPQuery');
```

**Unfortunately, although the posts_join is visible in the sql query, the posts_orderby is not transmitted.**

Here is the sql query of my result page :

```
   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_acf_google_map_search_geodata AS acf_gms_geo ON wp_posts.ID = acf_gms_geo.post_id WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (968) AND (
    wp_posts.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM wp_term_relationships
    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (10)
    )
    ) AND (
    wp_postmeta.meta_key = ‘total_sales’
    AND
    (
    (
    ( mt1.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_start’ AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) <= ‘20180125’ )
    AND
    ( mt2.meta_key = ‘flash_sale_end’ AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS DATE) >= ‘20180125’ )
    )
    )
    ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = ‘product’ 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = ‘publish’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘complete’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘paid’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘confirmed’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘unpaid’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘pending-confirmation’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘cancelled’ 
OR wp_posts.post_status = ‘private’) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

I think the orderby is not taken into account because woocomerce already has a default orderby in the sql query...

Do you know how to get it to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work !! As woocommerce has its own thing to order products, it was just necessary to write a function like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['lat']) and $_GET['lat'] != "" and isset($_GET['lng']) and $_GET['lng'] != "")
{
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' 

);
}
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {

    $lat = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lat'] );
    $lng = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['lng'] );

        $args['orderby'] = ' (POW((acf_gms_geo.lng-{$lng}),2) + POW((acf_gms_geo.lat-

{$lat}),2))';
        $args['order'] = 'ASC';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';

    return $args;
}
```